# MySQL - How to index this left join?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm having trouble indexing this left join :

```
SELECT comments.id, comments.topid, comments.username, comments.body, comments.dt, comments.active, users.email
FROM comments
LEFT JOIN registered_users.users
ON comments.username = users.username
WHERE postid = 12 AND active = 1
ORDER BY id desc
```

I have indexes on:

Comments -> keyname (postid) - postid, active, id

Users -> keyname (username) - username

The result I'm getting back is :

```
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys | key    | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | comments | ref  | postid        | postid | 5       | const,const |  116 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL   | NULL    | NULL        |    1 |                                 |
+----+-------------+----------+------+---------------+--------+---------+-------------+------+---------------------------------+
```

How can I fix this so I'm not "using temporary; using filesort" ?

Comment: But it's using an index. Is the performance not good?

Comment: The performance is so-so for now, but I have a feeling as the site receives more traffic it's going to be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps making an index with all three columns

## `comments` is an InnoDB table

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD INDEX new_index (active,postid,username);
```

## `comments` is a MyISAM table

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD INDEX new_index (active,postid,id,username);
```

## Why propose a new index?

Searching the `comments` table by the `postid` index will still require accessing the table intermittently to check the id and username columns. Having more columns from your `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses inside the index will lighten the work for the Optimizer.

## CAVEAT

Even if the retrieveal is a little faster, the filesort may be unavoidable because you said

```
ORDER BY id desc
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I still receive the same result : Using temporary; Using filesort

Comment: Removing "ORDER BY id desc" solved the issue. Now, just to figure out how to get the results in reverse order ..

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else has this issue, always make sure your JOIN tables are set to the same collation type.

My comments tables was set to "utf8_unicode_ci" - while I was trying to JOIN to users.email which was set to "latin1_swedish_ci".

If they are set differently, MySQL can't make use of any indexes.

I am now able to use ORDER BY, LIMIT clauses without the dreaded "filesort" issue.

Answer (score 0):

If active is a flag, there may not be enough selectivity for the optimizer to bother with it.  Have you tried having the index only on postid?

Comment: Yes, I get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Experience tells me to do this:

```
create index comments_postid on comments(postid);
```

And the other index you'd need would be is `users(username)` but you already have that.

It's a good idea to do this too:

```
analyze table comments, users;
```